# Visual Studio 2010, Office 2007 & 2010 Interopability

Tags: vsto, office-interop

On my development PC, I uninstalled Office 2007 and installed Office 2010.

I have a VS 2010 Solution that has several Excel 2007 templates (projects).

When I open the Solution, VS wants to "upgrade" the project (to Office 2010). I cancelled out of that and in the VS options, I turned off "Upgrade to latest version of Office".

Now, the solution opens fine, but the Excel 2007 template projects will not load or open. All the clients that run this appication have Office 2007 intalled, so I need to be able to continue to develop this application and target Office 2007.

Can anyone tell me how to do that? (I downloaded and installed the Office 2007 PIA...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a rule I always suggest running the version of office on your development machine that you are targeting, otherwise you loose F5 support and things often don't work as they should.

Another point is that if you do upgrade to Office 2010, the add-in will still work on 2007, as long as you do not access any of the 2010 API's. So technically if you upgrade the project to 2010, then remove the reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel v14 and add v12, that will restrict you to office 2007 API's, and you shouldn't have a problem.

Just give it a go, upgrade the project, then try install it into Office 2007, it *should* work fine. If not, just undo/revert your local changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is VSTO, VSTO 3.5 was office 2007, vsto 4 comes with VS2010 and is Office 2010.

You might check on what versions of VSTO are currently installed and make sure you've got the right ones.

Comment: As a side note, it's perfectly possible to run side by side versions of Office apps (other than Outlook, only a single version of it can be installed on a machine). At one point, I had a dev machine with Office 2000, XP, 2003, 2007 and 2010 installed and working fine.